# How to get maxpwdAge attribute value in ActiveDirectory using C++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, active-directory

i am working with AD Server,i want to get the **maxpwdAge attribute** value...

i already try ADSi for that,but it gives an issue.

```
VARIANT var;
bsNamingContext=L"maxpwdAge";

hr = ADsGetObject(pszADsPath, IID_IADsUser, (void**) &pUser);
if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
VariantInit(&var);
hr = pUser->Get(bsNamingContext, &var);  
}
```

but,it gives -2147463155 (8000500d) error...

but i am using  `bsNamingContext=L"cn";`
it gives the CN values correctly...

anyone can resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[maxpwdAge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676863%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is not included in user/contact/person LDAP class, so you can not retrieve it that way.

You need to query it from **domain** object, not **user** object

Try this:

```
Const ONE_HUNDRED_NANOSECOND = .000000100   ' .000000100 is equal to 10^-7
Const SECONDS_IN_DAY = 86400

Set objDomain = GetObject("LDAP://DC=fabrikam,DC=com")     ' LINE 4
Set objMaxPwdAge = objDomain.Get("maxPwdAge")              ' LINE 5

If objMaxPwdAge.LowPart = 0 Then
  WScript.Echo "The Maximum Password Age is set to 0 in the " & _
               "domain. Therefore, the password does not expire."
  WScript.Quit
Else
  dblMaxPwdNano = Abs(objMaxPwdAge.HighPart * 2^32 + objMaxPwdAge.LowPart)
  dblMaxPwdSecs = dblMaxPwdNano * ONE_HUNDRED_NANOSECOND   ' LINE 13
  dblMaxPwdDays = Int(dblMaxPwdSecs / SECONDS_IN_DAY)      ' LINE 14
  WScript.Echo "Maximum password age: " & dblMaxPwdDays & " days"
End If
```

**UPDATE:**

To convert large integer to human readable value use [IADsLargeInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa706037%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) dispatch interface

**Note 1** : Example is in VB, but you can easily rewrite it, because of COM.

**Note 2** : maxpwdAge is not configured per user, but per domain (until fine-grained password policies are enabled)

**Further readings:**

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974598.aspx **[Recommended]**
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc220201%28prot.20%29.aspx
- http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/AD%20Determining%20Password%20Expiration
- http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/Domain%20Wide%20Account%20Policies

Comment: @ rkosegi,i got a solution for my question...But i have another doubt.. **mypwdage value is 432000...and my pwdlastsetvalue is 41208.467858796299...Now how to convert this time value into day value...how to get password expiry day using C++ win32 API?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135747/how-to-get-pwdexpirydate-using-pwdlastset-value-and-maxpwdage-value-in-c-win32

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this one too. Eventually, I was able to get it with the following criteria.

```
baseDN: 'DC=myofficedomain,DC=local',
filter: '(objectClass=domain)',
attributes: ['maxPwdAge']
```

I hope this helps anyone else using ldapsearch or NodeJS with ActiveDirectory.