# how to get pwdexpirydate using pwdlastset value and maxpwdage value in C++ win32 API?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, active-directory, adsi

i get the maxpwdage value and pwdlastset value using ADSI..

Now i want to check the password expiry date...

`hr = pDomain->get_MaxPasswordAge(&ret);`

maxpwdage gives 432000...

`hr = pUser->get_PasswordLastChanged(&expirationDate);`

pwdlastset gives 41176.470196759263...

how to achieve the password expiry date using this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MaxPasswordAge**

- Indicates the maximum time interval, in seconds, after which the password must be changed by the user.

**PasswordLastChanged**

- The last time the password was changed.

You need to add MaxPasswordAge to PasswordLastChanged.

**VARIANT date**

Type: DATE

- A date and time value. Dates are represented as double-precision numbers, where midnight, January 1, 1900 is 2.0, January 2, 1900 is 3.0, and so on.
- The date can be converted to and from an MS-DOS representation using VariantTimeToDosDateTime.

So this means that 1.0 represent one day.

**from WTypes.h :**

```
typedef double DATE;
```

So:

```
DATE expirationDate;
VARIANT vtExpDate;

expirationDate += (double)(ret / 86400);

vtExpDate.vt = VT_DATE ;
vtExpDate.date = date ;
```

86400 = 24 * 60 * 60 = seconds/day

Then use [VariantTimeToDosDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get human readable date.

Comment: @ rkosegi: in `expirationDate.date` .date...how can u have tha date property,i cant get any property after using `.` , `->` , `::` ...

Comment: @SanjuMonu : Sorry, I expected you are using VARIANT instead of DATE.Please see updated answer.