# Set domain password policy using LDAP with "maxPwdAge" error?

Tags: c#, ldap, password-policy

```
var data = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://xxx.xxx", LdapAdUserName, LdapAdPassword);
data.data.Properties["LockoutThreshold"].Value = 10;`
data.data.Properties["maxPwdAge"].Value = 90;
data.CommitChanges();
```

I'm try to change domain password policy on AD.
First, i try to update "LockoutThreshold" => OK
Second, i try to update "maxPwdAge" => Exception when commit

Exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException' occurred in System.DirectoryServices.dll but was not handled in user code
```

Why can not set "maxPwdAge" ??

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you need to be Domain Administrator, and maybe this will help [How to get maxpwdAge attribute value in ActiveDirectory using C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13123075/how-to-get-maxpwdage-attribute-value-in-activedirectory-using-c), this is on C++ but principle is the same.