# Get maxPwdAge using Winldap.h in C++

Tags: c++, active-directory, ldap

How can I get maxPwdAge using winldap.h in C++ ? I am able to get all the entries of a user but as maxPwdAge property is of domain I don't know how can I read and get the desired value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get maxpwdAge attribute value in ActiveDirectory using C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13123075/how-to-get-maxpwdage-attribute-value-in-activedirectory-using-c)

Comment: No, It uses adsids.h whereas I am using winldap.h.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the piece of code I used to get the maxPwdAge

```
   std::string Imaxpasswordage = "";
        result = ldap_search_s(ldap, _T("DC=XXXXXX,DC=XXXXXX"), scope, _T("(maxPwdAge=*)"),
            NULL, attrsonly, &answer);
    
        if (result != LDAP_SUCCESS) {
            error = result;
            return result;
        }
        entries_found = ldap_count_entries(ldap, answer);
        for (entry = ldap_first_entry(ldap, answer);
            entry != NULL;
            entry = ldap_next_entry(ldap, entry)) {
    
            for (attribute = ldap_first_attribute(ldap, entry, &ber);
                attribute != NULL;
                attribute = ldap_next_attribute(ldap, entry, ber)) {
                if ((values = ldap_get_values(ldap, entry, attribute)) != NULL) {
                    int compare = wcscmp(attribute, _T("maxPwdAge"));
                    if (compare == 0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; values[i] != NULL; i++)
                        {
                            char Temp[2000];
    
                            wcstombs(Temp, values[i], 2000);
                            std::wstring str(values[i]);
                            std::string str0(str.begin() + 1, str.end());
                            Imaxpasswordage = str0;
                            break;
                        }
                        ldap_value_free(values);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```